# Custom UITabBar that expand on selection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to achieve the below attach image on the UITabbar.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PAvS.png

It's pretty straight forward, on selection the tab expand with a label to display text and on selection on another tab, the selected tab will collapse.

I am not really sure how to do this with the UItabbar.

I will appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe to clarify a little basically the tab on the right in the image is already selected. While the one on the left is not selected. While the tab is selected, it should expand and collaspe the rest of the tabs and show a label with text for the current tab eg "settings"

Answer (score 1):

for the custom tab you use this method on appdelegate class
this method create two tab bar item.
and you set your image..

```
-(void)SetTabs
{

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

NSMutableArray *localControllerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:2];


UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];
GreetingCardsViewController *GreetingCardsView = [[[GreetingCardsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GreetingCardsViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Home" image:image tag:0];
UINavigationController *GreetingCardsViewNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:GreetingCardsView];
GreetingCardsView.tabBarItem = item;
[localControllerArray addObject:GreetingCardsViewNavigationController];


UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"heart1.png"];
Cards *CardView = [[[Cards alloc] initWithNibName:@"Cards" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cards" image:image1 tag:1];
UINavigationController *CardNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:CardView];
CardNavigationController.tabBarItem = item1;
[localControllerArray addObject:CardNavigationController];  
[tabBarController setViewControllers:localControllerArray];
[_window addSubview:tabBarController.view]; 
[localControllerArray release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after, however I think [this](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/) may be relevant to you. You could use the basic concept and tweak it to what you need.